# Static redirect on windows?

Tags: windows, networking, dns, redirection, port-redirection

So I want to create a static redirect - or: a local domain.

What I want to type in my browser

```
http://plex.home/
```

*It's not necessary to have a fake TLD - i.e. **.net** would be okay too*

Where I want to get

```
http://192.168.178.2:32400/manage/index.html
```

What solutions are there to get this working on a windows computer?

I guess setting up a custom DNS server would be the most efficient way (especially for mobile devices etc). But for now this is not a solution.

Comment: So, now that the URL is fixed, the problem is the port. If you connect to `http://plex.home`, it’s actually port 80. Would it be possible to run an additional web server on your Plex box? What kind of system is it anyway?

Answer (score 3):

Try your C:/Windows/System32/etc/hosts file to configure a redirect from plex.home to 192.168.178.2, configure a redirect on the 192.168.178.2 server to the folder you want.

Comment: Out of curiosity could you detail how to (for a windows server or a win7/8 machine running a server) you could create the redirect to the desired folder? I understand modifying the hosts file, but am not certain about what you do next. Thanks!

Comment: @Abraxas some low-resource web server . ie. lighttpd on nix. actually some python script could be enough - IIS on Windows would be way to OP ;-)